# Localhost Server Refusing Connection

Tags: python, django, localhost, port

I just set up Django on a dreamhost server. Ran through everything, but can't seem to get the welcome page. I got to the point where it says "Development server is running at 127.0.0.1:8002 (tried with 8000 but got the "that port is already in use error). When I try to access that address in my browser in Chrome I get Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): The server refused the connection.

Any idea why this is happening? I am stuck in a loop, I have no clue what is going on. Help is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to know your server's IP or domain address. If you used example.com to access you server SSH, then launching Django with

> ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8002

and accessing it with `http://example.com:8002` should work. But if you only know IP, then launch Django with that IP instead of

> 0.0.0.0

and access it with `http://YOUR-IP:8002`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, that helped. It is working now, thank you for helping me with this! Much appreciated

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that django is listening on `localhost` this means you won't be able to access the server directly via the internet. To change that you can specify the port/hostname for django:

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8002
```

If you don't want to make the server directly accessible via the internet you can do port forwarding with ssh:

```
ssh -L8002:localhost:8002 server
```

This will forward your local port 8002 via ssh to the remote server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mru
When I tried the first one, and then tried to access the 0.0.0.0:8002 with the browser I got Error 108 (net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID): Unknown error.

When I tried the other command I got the response "ssh: Could not resolve hostname server: Name or service not known"