# Webapplication created with django refusing connection after importing reverse in views

Tags: python, django

I want to redirect from one page to another in my web application and want to use the reverse function. Everything works perfectly (except the redirect), but when I import
`from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse`
in my view.py file, suddenly my access is denied and the following error pops up:
127.0.0.1 has refused the connection
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

This happens after the import. No other code is added

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be helpful: [Localhost Server Refusing Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640720/localhost-server-refusing-connection)

If your problem remains, you need to provide more info (view code).